# How to check network folder exist with credentials using powershell 5

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-5.0

Lest say there is a network folder `\\my_server\my_root\my_dir`.
To access this folder these credentials required username: `my_doman\my_user` password: `my_password`.

Now in my program first it try to map network folder to a local drive. If there is a exception, it consider as folder not exist. I think this is not a good way.

Is there a way to check this folder exist without try to map to a local drive? I'm looking for something like

`[System.IO.Path]::Exist("\\my_server\my_root\my_dir","my_doman\my_user","my_password")`

I'm using `Powershell 5`

This is how I map the drive now

```
try{
    $net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
    $net.MapNetworkDrive($free_drive, $network_dir, $false, "domain\user", "password")
}catch{
  Write-host: "folder does not exist"
}
```

Comment: How are you mapping a drive currently?

Comment: You can use `New-PSDrive -Name P -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\my_server\my_root\my_dir" -Credential "my_domain\my_user"`

Comment: @Bacon: added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using [New-PSDrive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/New-PSDrive):

```
New-PSDrive -Name Q -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\my_server\my_root\my_dir -Credential my_domain\my_user -Persist
```

Old School method using cmdline utility:

```
net use \\my_server\my_root\my_dir /user:my_domain\my_user my_password
start \\my_server\my_root\my_dir
```

For mapping you can use this:

```
$net = New-Object -comobject Wscript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("Q:","\\my_server\my_root\my_dir",0,"my_domain\my_user","my_password")
```

For testing the path, you can use:

```
Test-Path \\my_server\my_root\my_dir
```

Note:You will get a boolean value in return from the test path.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! but these all fail if network folder not exist. I'm looking for a way to check folder really exist before mapping. because mapping could be fail because of other reasons too.

Comment: You can check that using `test-path`. Let me update my answer

Comment: @RanadipDutta - The problem using Test-Path is that you can't pass credentials to it.

Comment: Thats why you need to use psdrive.. I dont think of any other alternative at this point.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: as if now, even i dont have an alternative. M looking at the dot net classes if there is any way to have that checked without mapping the drive. :)

Comment: It should be possible to just run a powershell script as another user and run Test-Path in that users context.

Comment: ya, thats a nice approach. I have never tried that. but yes , logically it should be

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that on the machine executing the script you're able to log in as the user under which you want to connect to the remote share, you could use `Invoke-Command` to invoke `Test-Path` as another user:

```
$pathExists = Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {
    Test-Path -Path "\\my_server\my_root\my_dir"
}
if ($pathExists)
{
    # my_dir\ exists
}
else
{
    # my_dir\ is inaccessible/non-existent
}
```

I'm not in a position to test this at present but I suspect you may need to include `-Authentication Credssp` as a parameter to `Invoke-Command` (assuming the necessary environment for that is in place) due to the double-hop problem.

Of course, if you're checking for the existence of that directory under another user in order to make decisions for future filesystem operations to be executed as that same user, you would then need to `Invoke-Command` another batch of operations or include them after `Test-Path`.  At that point you might be better off connecting to the share under alternate credentials in the usual way.  It's just the difference between *executing* as another user and *connecting* as another user, each with their own pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem checking the folder and/or file existence on a remote server before copying the file from deployment server.  Nothing worked for me and ended up in a huge frustration.

I then tried this...

```
$pathExists = Invoke-Command -ComputerName <remoteServerName> -Credential $credentials 
-ScriptBlock {
Test-Path -Path <AbsolutePath> "UNC path does not work here and you must use Absolute 
path.  eg. instead of \\Server use D:\Dir1 or D:\Dir1\File1.bat"
}
if (-not ($pathExists))
{
write-host "Directory or File does not exist"
}
else
{
 write-host "Directory or File exist"
}
```

This worked just fine for me after using the **absolute** path in the Test-Path.  For some reason the UNC path does not work!  Hope, this helps someone!